# Incorrect target range in Worksheet_Change event

Tags: vba, excel, events, worksheet

I am an Excel-VBA newcomer and I am trying to write a short piece of code which is triggered by somebody changing the value of cells in a worksheet. It should set the value of the **changed** cell to zero if it's less than zero. The code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Debug.Print Target.Address
 If Target.Column = 6 Then
  For Each Cell In Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3)
     If Cell.Value < 0 Then
        Cell.Value = 0
     End If
  Next
 End If
End Sub
```

Now what happens is that when I change the value of any cell in column 6, every cell in the sheet containing numbers less than zero is *also* changed to zero.

I was thinking that the "Target" Object that is created for the `Worksheet_Change` event handler would only contain the cell/cells changed, and thus my code would only change the value of cells that were modified and triggered the event in the first place.

I tried to help myself by using `Debug.Print` to output the address of the object. It printed out the address of every cell in the sheet with a value less than zero, so I assume the handler ran several times.

I actually found a workaround for the problem itself but my questions are these: how did I fail in using the Worksheet_Change event and what can I do in the future to not have such problems?

Comment: Use application.enableevents = false or your event procedure will run on top of itself.

Comment: `Target` does relate only to the cell(s) changed, and I cannot replicate your error. Try Jeeped's amendment and see how you get on.

Comment: Don't forget to set it back to `Application.EnableEvents = True` afterwards otherwise your Event won't fire next time

Comment: Define it globally maybe in WorkBook_open action listener `Application.EnableEvents = True`

And your code is working fine

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Debug.Print Target.Address

 If Target.Column = 6 Then

  For Each Cell In Target
     If Cell.Value < 0 Then
        Cell.Value = 0
    End If
 Next
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 1:** Updated code with bug fix suggested in comments

**EDIT 2:** Updated code with error handling to deal with Array Formulae

In answer to your question

> **[1]** how did I fail in using the Worksheet_Change event and **[2]** what can I do in the future to not have such problems?

1. Technically you didn't
2. Nothing for this type of problem, although the following rule helps in general

You are correct in your understanding of the `Target`object. Your code failed because `SpecialCells` doesn't like a single cell to operate on. Give it one and it expands it to the ***entire*** sheet! Give it anything else and it works just fine.

The reason your `Debug.Print` displays all the cells is that every time your code changes a cell, ***another*** change event is triggered. Luckily for you the second one finds a zero so it doesn't trigger *another* one. The following general rule should help avoid a lot of problems, just not this particular one:

- **Always surround any code in an event handler that changes any part of the workbook with `Application.EnableEvents`**.

To fix you code so it works, simply remove the `SpecialCells` method call. Since you are using `Cell.Value` instead of the highly recommended `Cell.Value2` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46052777/1961728)), VBA implicit type converts numbers formatted as text to actual numbers for you. Thus the code works both on numeric and text values.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  'Debug.Print Target.Address;
  Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Cell In Target '.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3)
      If Cell.Column = 6 And Cell.Value < 0 Then
        On Error GoTo Error:
        Cell.Value = 0
        On Error GoTo 0
      End If
    Next
GoTo ExitSub:
Error:
  If Err.Number = 1004 Then ' 1004 -> "You cannot change part of an array."
    'Application.Undo ' Uncomment to disallow array entering a negative value formula into/across column 6
    MsgBox "A cell could not be zeroed as" & vbCr & "it is part of an array formula.", vbExclamation, "Microsoft Office Excel"
    On Error GoTo 0
  Else
    On Error GoTo 0
    Resume
  End If
ExitSub:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

<sub>Notes:</sub>

<sub>- Update 1: Code now correctly deals with multi-cell changes.</sub>

<sub>- Update 2: Code now traps error 1004 to deal with entering Array Formulae. It can either allow the array formula to be entered resulting in negative values in column 6, or stop the entry altogether.</sub>

Comment: I avoided to use target.column, because one can enter data in an horizontal range using ctrl+enter.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Not sure I understand. You can also enter data in a *vertical* range as well. The formula has to be different though.

Comment: `Target` might be a range, and cover several columns. Therefore `If Target.Column = 6` is prone to error.

Comment: Got it now! I've updated to code in the answer so that only column 6 values are zeroed even if a multi-column-spanning range is changed at the same time.

Comment: Thank both of you it works fine with both solutions!

Answer (score 0):

This works  (**Updated**)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target
        If c.Column = 6 Then If IsNumeric(c) Then If c < 0 Then c = 0
    Next c
End Sub
```

And please, learn and use `OPTION EXPLICIT` !

Comment: I can't get this to work with the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants,3)`

Comment: Also what's the 3 for. It's not covered in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel)

Comment: @Tom: according to documentation 3 is equal to `xlNumbers + xlTextValues`. And that works, I just tried

Comment: Thanks - missed the bit about adding them together

Comment: Patrick & @Tom You should always use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers + xlTextValues)` so your code is self-documenting. Tom, see my answer for why you can't get it working.

Comment: Thank both of you it works fine with both solutions!

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a way to stop my worksheet from "flashing" as it ran code to format columns and rows, due to users changing data anywhere in the sheet, including Filters and Sorting.

Aside, from the official answer to the OP's problem, If you're trying to control the `Worksheet_Change()` event from firing **at all** (it will still fire but you can bypass it), in circumstances where you want users to change data for example, but not areas around the data, such as fields or labels as part of your VBA system, I use the `Target.Row` element to determine my limits. Combined with `Target.Column`, and you can hone-in on specific cells that are free for the user to control.

i.e.

```
Dim myTopLimit AS Integer
myTopLimit = 6
etc..etc
if Target.Row < myTopLimit and Target.Row > myBottomLimit and Target.Column < myLeftLimit and Target.Column > myRightLimit then
.... code to allow WorkSheet_Change() to do somthing
else
.... code to force WorkSheet_Change() to drop through or no code
End If
```