# WorksheetFunction.Sum returning zero for numbers

Tags: excel, vba

Clean up your code, kiddies.  After much wailing and gnashing of teeth, the problem turned out to be the extra parentheses I had in my .Sum arguments.  Big thanks to @BigBen and @JvdV.

**The Problem:**  Worksheetfunction.Sum returns a sum of 0 for a dynamic range, but only for rows.count > 1 *and* only for currency-formatted reference data.

**More Detail:**  I have a userform set up to scrape a reference workbook and return a different number into each of four different textboxes based on user input.  On occasion the numbers will need to be a sum of several rows on the reference workbook.  Using my code below, this works like a dream for every return textbox as long as the number of rows is 1, but returns 0 (or $0.00 as it were) for anything else.  **However,** it works just fine in all circumstances for the one sum that is just an integer.  The rest are formatted as currency.

**What I've done:**  Using MsgBoxes I've verified that the dynamic range returns the correct addresses, i.e. all cells I want summed and that the numbers at those addresses are in fact numbers and not text (verified by a True return for IsNumber).  I've tried using .Subtotal and .Aggregate to see if those might help, but I ran into Missing Object and other errors and ran away whimpering because I'm new to VBA.

**The Code:**

My basic logic is as follows:  Search in every sheet of the reference (csrWorkbook) for textbox.value.  Once found, measure the height of the merged area (I know I know, but the merging decision is made above my paygrade).  Offset to the right to find 4 different related quantities.  Sum these quantities if multiple rows exist.  Return the sum to four different textboxes.

Help!

```
    Private Sub ScrapeButton_Click()

    'Enter search term into first TB
    'click search button
    'result DOES(!!) appear in second TB

    'Variables
    Dim csrWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim refWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim refVariables As Worksheet
    Dim csrFilePath As String
    Dim csrFileName As String
    Dim slinAddress As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sheetCount As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim slinCell As Excel.Range
    Dim quantCells As Excel.Range
    Dim costCells As Excel.Range
    Dim feeCells As Excel.Range
    Dim totalCells As Excel.Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iCost As Double
    Dim iFee As Double
    Dim iTotal As Double


    Set refWorkbook = Workbooks("AutomationBackbone.xlsm")
    csrFileName = refWorkbook.Sheets("Variable Storage").Range("A2").Value
    Set csrWorkbook = Workbooks(csrFileName)

    sheetCount = csrWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    'search all worksheets for data in a known column
    For i = 1 To sheetCount
        Set slinCell = csrWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("C1:C100").find(Me.TextBox1.Value)
            If Not slinCell Is Nothing Then

                'Find sums and populate
                rowCount = slinCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count 'count the number of rows in merged area
                Set quantCells = slinCell.Offset(0, 2).Resize(rowCount, 1) 'establish a new range of that same height
                Set costCells = quantCells.Offset(0, 6)
                Set feeCells = quantCells.Offset(0, 7)
                Set totalCells = quantCells.Offset(0, 8)

                Me.iQuantityTB.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum((quantCells)) 'populate the Initial Quantity
                iCost = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum((costCells)) 'find sum of Cost range
                iFee = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum((feeCells)) 'find sum of Fee range
                iTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum((totalCells)) 'find sum of Total range

                Me.iCostTB.Value = iCost 'populate textboxes
                Me.iFeeTB.Value = iFee
                Me.iTotalTB.Value = iTotal

'original code commented out to see if being more explicit helped.
     'Narrator: it didn't
                'Me.iCostTB.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum((quantCells.Offset(0, 6))) 'populate the Initial Cost
                'Me.iFeeTB.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum((quantCells.Offset(0, 7))) 'populate the Initial Fee
                'Me.iTotalTB.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum((quantCells.Offset(0, 8))) 'populate the Initial Total

                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub
```

**Edit:** Pics added for clarity.

[image: This approximates the format of the data I'm trying to pull and sum to populate textboxes]

Comment: I believe so, yes.  I tested them in a separate cell with `=IsNumber([Cell1])` which came back with True.

Comment: Apparently I'm too new to embed pics directly, but there's now a link in my question.  Let me know if it's unclear.

Comment: Side note: you don't need the extra parentheses: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum((quantCells))` -> `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(quantCells)`

Comment: Just to verfiy - given the screenshot you've posted, what does `? Application.Sum(Range("E2:E4"))` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: It returns 1368 using ` MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum((refWorkbook.Sheets("PR Generator").Range("E2:E4")))`

Comment: If that works, then your range reference is off.

Comment: Not knowing which column contain what data makes it hard to test your code =). If column A in your screenshot is actually column C, and you got two columns of irrelevant data, then `Offset` by two columns to `Set quantCells` makes little sense.

Comment: @bigben that's part of what's so frustrating--I've verified that the address is correct.  I had a MsgBox pop up the range I want to sum and it matches where the numbers are.


The pic I added is just an approximation I whipped up, JvdV.  I can't post my actual reference but this should be good enough to show the format.

Comment: I hope I'm not coming across as snarky, I really appreciate y'all taking a look!

Comment: That's all fine, I'm just trying to replicate your issue as it's interesting =). I'm just hoping it's not an `Offset` issue. Here a thing > **Remove** the double paranthesis! e.g.: `iCost = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum((costCells))` > `iCost = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(costCells)` etc.

Comment: SOLVED:  It was the gd extra parentheses.  Still a big dang mystery why the quantity (vice money) shrugged it off, but at least it's working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Parentheses strike again!**

---

Including the extra parentheses causes the inner expression to be *evaluated*, and the result to be passed to `Sum`.

So

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum((costCells))
```

is equivalent to

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(costCells.Value)
```

which returns zero when the underlying data is `Currency`.

As a small reproducible example for `Sum`s behavior here (which is not what I expected):

```
Dim x(0 To 1) As Currency
x(0) = 1
x(1) = 2

Debug.Print Application.Sum(x) '<~ returns zero.
```

Note that `.Value2` does *not* use the `Currency` data type, and the line

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(costCells.Value2)
```

would return the correct result regardless of the underlying value.

Note that similar behavior has been noted and explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46052777/9758194).

Comment: Big dang mystery solved.  What a world.

Comment: Shows you why parentheses are important :-) This makes me wonder if something similar caused MSFT to introduce `Value2`.

Comment: The reason is that `WorksheetFunction.Sum()` does not **understand** `Currency` nor `Date` data type. As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46052777/9758194). Therefor it will return zero. And as @BigBen mentioned, the paranthesis create an array of your `Range` objects. Therefor, the `.Sum` no longer evaluates a `Range` but `Array`

Comment: @JvdV - good find. Added into the body of the answer.

Comment: @JvdV - now that you have a gold badge you could have closed as duplicate too :-)

Comment: I know but it shocked me this morning when I saw it happen for the first time. I re-opened because it was based on just my, read a single, opinion. =). I guess it takes getting used to